# Instantiate a generic adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am a newbie in recyclerview. I have created my generic adapter for different properties by following the @SebastienRieu's answer, i.e. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078114/recyclerview-with-different-types-and-different-adapter/68280416#68280416). The problem is that I want to **instantiate the adapter** and set it to my recyclerview. How Do I do that?

Here, 2nd parameter is context. What should replace the 1st paramenter with?

```
GenericModelAdapter adapter= new GenericModelAdapter(??, this)
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any help is appreciated.

My PostModelClass:

```
public class PostsModelClass {
    int userId;
    int id;
    String title;

    @SerializedName("body")
    String textBody;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getTextBody() {
        return textBody;
    }
}
```

Similarly, here's my CommentsModelclass:

```
public class CommentsModelClass {
    String postId;
    String id;
    String name;
    String email;

    @SerializedName("body")
    String textBody;

    public String getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getTextBody() {
        return textBody;
    }
```

And here's my adapter:

```
    public class GenericModelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    
        private Context mContext;
        private static final int TYPE_POSTS = 10;
        private static final int TYPE_COMMENTS = 11;
        private static final int TYPE_PHOTOS = 12;
        private static final int TYPE_USERS = 13;
        private List<GenericViewModel> mItems;
    
    
        public GenericModelAdapter(List<GenericViewModel> items, Context context) {
            this.mItems = items;
            this.mContext = context;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            GenericViewModel genericItems = mItems.get(position);
            if (genericItems.isPostsModel()) {
                return TYPE_POSTS;
            } else if (genericItems.isCommentsModel()) {
                return TYPE_COMMENTS;
            } else if (genericItems.isPhotosModel()) {
                return TYPE_PHOTOS;
            } else {
                return TYPE_USERS;
            }
        }
    
        public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView textViewResult;
    
            PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textViewResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            }
        }
    
        public static class CommentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView textViewResult;
    
            CommentsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textViewResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            }
        }
    
        public static class PhotosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView textViewResult;
    
            PhotosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textViewResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            }
        }
    
        public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
            TextView textViewResult;
    
            UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textViewResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            }
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            if (viewType == TYPE_POSTS) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(rootView);
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_COMMENTS) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                return new CommentsViewHolder(rootView);
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_PHOTOS) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                return new PhotosViewHolder(rootView);
            } else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(rootView);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
            GenericViewModel genericViewModel = mItems.get(position);
            if (genericViewModel.isPostsModel()) {
                onBindPost(holder, genericViewModel.getPostsModelClass());
            } else if (genericViewModel.isCommentsModel()) {
                //onBindComments(holder, genericViewModel.getCommentsModelClass());
            } else if (genericViewModel.isPhotosModel()) {
                //onBindPhotos(holder, genericViewModel.getPhotosModelClass());
            } else if (genericViewModel.isUsersModel()) {
                //onBindUsers(holder, genericViewModel.getUsersModelClass());
            }
        }
    
        private void onBindPost(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, PostsModelClass postsModelClass) {
    
            String content = "User ID: " + postsModelClass.getUserId() +
                    "\nID: " + postsModelClass.getId() +
                    "\nTitle: " + postsModelClass.getTitle() +
                    "\nBody: " + postsModelClass.getTextBody();
    
            ((PostViewHolder) holder).textViewResult.setText(content);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }
    }
```

And lastly, My GenericViewModel:

```
    public class GenericViewModel {
    
        private PostsModelClass mPostsModelClass;
        private CommentsModelClass mCommentsModelClass;
        private PhotosModelClass mPhotosModelClass;
        private UsersModelClass mUsersModelClass;
    
        private GenericViewModel(PostsModelClass postsModelClass, CommentsModelClass commentsModelClass, PhotosModelClass photosModelClass, UsersModelClass usersModelClass) {
            this.mPostsModelClass = postsModelClass;
            this.mCommentsModelClass = commentsModelClass;
            this.mPhotosModelClass = photosModelClass;
            this.mUsersModelClass = usersModelClass;
        }
    
        public boolean isPostsModel() {
            return mPostsModelClass != null;
        }
    
        public boolean isCommentsModel() {
            return mCommentsModelClass != null;
        }
    
        public boolean isPhotosModel() {
            return mPhotosModelClass != null;
        }
    
        public boolean isUsersModel() {
            return mUsersModelClass != null;
        }
    
    
        public static GenericViewModel getPostsInstance(PostsModelClass modelClass) {
            return new GenericViewModel(modelClass, null, null, null);
        }
    
        public static GenericViewModel getCommentsInstance(CommentsModelClass modelClass) {
            return new GenericViewModel(null, modelClass, null, null);
        }
    
        public static GenericViewModel getPhotosInstance(PhotosModelClass modelClass) {
            return new GenericViewModel(null, null, modelClass, null);
        }
    
        public static GenericViewModel getUsersInstance(UsersModelClass modelClass) {
            return new GenericViewModel(null, null, null, modelClass);
        }
    
        public PostsModelClass getPostsModelClass() {
            return mPostsModelClass;
        }
    
        public CommentsModelClass getCommentsModelClass() {
            return mCommentsModelClass;
        }
    
        public PhotosModelClass getPhotosModelClass() {
            return mPhotosModelClass;
        }
    
        public UsersModelClass getUsersModelClass() {
            return mUsersModelClass;
        }
    
    }
```

Yes, I haven't shared the model classes for Posts and Users. They are similar to these model classes and I'd implement them later.

Here's the error I'm facing:

[image: Arguments Error]

Comment: What does the constructor in your `GenericModelAdapter` class excpect?

Comment: can you post your adapter code

Comment: I have shared my adapter code by editing the question. This is the reference website I'm using: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reference you gave in the question, you need a model that contains all your different properties like **EventViewModel** in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078114/recyclerview-with-different-types-and-different-adapter/68280416#68280416) and populate the list based on the viewType.

```
ArrayList<EventViewModel> eventList = "YOUR LIST"
GenericModelAdapter adapter= new GenericModelAdapter(eventList, this)
```

Comment: Thanks @Brendon for your reply. I've implemented the same but i'm getting the error in arguments. I've edited my question and added all the other portions of code. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

It must be ArrayList of different collected properties:

```
GenericModelAdapter adapter= new GenericModelAdapter(ArrayList<YourModel> eventList, this)
```

Your model:

```
public class YourModel() {

  private Property1 mProperty1;
  private Property2 mProperty2;

  private YourModel(Property1 property1, Property2 property2) {
    this.mProperty1 = property1;
    this.mProperty2 = property2;
  }

  public boolean isProperty1() {
    return mProperty1 != null
  }
  public boolean isProperty2() {
    return mProperty2 != null
  }

  public static YourModel getProperty1Instance(Property1 property1) {
    return new YourModel(property1, null);
  }
  public static EventViewModel getProperty2Instance(Property1 property2) {
    return new YourModel(null, property2);
  }

  public Property1 getProperty1() {
    return mProperty1;
  }
  public Property2 getProperty2() {
    return mProperty2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tugrul for your reply. I've implemented the same but i'm getting the error in arguments. I've edited my question and added all the other portions of code. Please refer to it.

Comment: `List<PostModelClass>` must be `List<GenericViewModel>` in `showPosts()` function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How will I mention that I want to use `PostModelClass` or `CommentsModelCLass` with the adapter then?

Comment: You will just add your `CommentsModelCLass` and `PostModelClass` to your `GenericViewModel` like this : `new GenericViewModel(new PostModelClass(), null)` or `new GenericViewModel(null, new CommentsModelCLass())` , later add this objects to your `List<GenericViewModel> genericList`, etc.

Comment: Well, still no luck. Thank you @tugrul for the answer anyway. I might ditch the concept of using generic adapters as and create separate adapters for each list. Makes it easy for maintaining code as well.
However, if you find any usable and similar Generic Adapter example on the internet please do mention them! :)